# Use of regression-trees to determine probabilities for a binary variable

Tags: probability, classification, random-forest, cart, rpart

I have a binary variable (sold/not sold) and I have used the CART algorithm in R (rpart) to build a classification tree to predict if this product is getting sold or not.
Now I would like to add a probability to this. How can I do this?
Can I just take the same Test/Trainingsdata from before and just build a regression tree on it or is this not gonna work? 
Can I somehow use the trees I got from the classification? 
And how could I evaluate the solution? 
Or is there a better approach to deal with this?
Thank you very, very much!

Answer (score 2):

From predict.[rpart](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/rpart.pdf) "If the rpart object is a classification tree, then the default is to return prob predictions, a matrix whose columns are the probability of the first, second, etc. class", so all you need to do is apply your fitted model to test/new data: *predict(model, newdata)*, where *type = "prob"* is the default. And if you are not getting that, check if it runs in classification mode (does summary(model) output classes or mean/MSE?) and if not convert your (already binary) response variable to factor <-*as.factor(x)*  This is almost identical for RF in randomForest.